# Why doesn't c program print error message to stderr when system call fails?

Tags: c, system-calls, errno

Below is a snippet of simple c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  FILE *fd = fopen("nothing", "r");
  // perror("fopen");
  return 0;
}
```

it prints nothing, but if `perror("fopen")` is uncommented, it prints

`fopen: No such file or directory`

according to `perror`'s man page

> When a system call fails, it usually returns -1 and sets the variable
>          errno to a value describing what went wrong.

and `No such file or directory` corresponds to `errno = 2`

since `stderr` is unbuffered, it seems like only when `perror` is called, then would error message be written to `stderr`, why does c program implicitly ignore the error (`errno` modified) rather than immediately writing it to `stderr`?

**Extra questions...**
Are there other ways to trigger `stderr`'s writing? Do we always have to trigger it 'manually' or can c program in some cases 'automatically' make it like java throws run-time exceptions?

Comment: What? Of course it doesn't print an error if `perror()` is not being called? I don't understand.

Comment: @unwind `errno` is set to `2` whether `perror()` is called or not, so error indeed happens

Comment: Yes, but by looking at the return value of `fopen` and at `errno` you can tell. It is up to you, the programmer, to decide whether to communicate and how to handle this error, because you know whether it is critical or not.

Comment: Hi @MOehm can you check my added questions please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure whether it would be better to open a new question instead of using the old one to as extra questions, especially, since there is already an answer that adresses the original question.

Comment: Why would anyone want to have *every* internal error printed when it can easily be handled by the program? Only errors that are not handled by the program should be reported to the user. If  a program bothers me wich an error message everytime a function returns `-1` and `EAGAIN` I would rather dump that program.

Comment: As to your extra question: You can always write wrapper functions that behave like the library functions and that log an error if something goes wrong. (Yes, there are many functions in the standard lib, but you can create the wrappers as you go, when you need them.)

Comment: *like java throws run-time exceptions?*  Java doesn't automagically emit errors to `stderr` either, even for exceptions - unless perhaps if you totally fail to handle the exception.  If you want your code to emit an error message to `stderr`, you have to write the  code to do that.

Comment: @MOehm And wrappers were the first thing the eminent late [W. Richard Stevens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W._Richard_Stevens) did in his exercises. I also remember elaborate "if-error-complain-and-exit" wrappers in SGI headers. So it is a reasonable thing to do and can de-clutter carefully written code.

Comment: Adding "extra questions" immediately renders existing answers incomplete, which is unfair on anyone who took the trouble to answer.  SO is not a discussion forum.  If you have new questions, post a new question.  But stderr is an output stream like any other and any stdio output function that takes a stream argument can write to it.

Comment: Hi @Clifford, the fact that I didn't pick your answer is not because my extra questions not being covered, but I think your stating that 'failing opening a file is not system error' is not convincing enough, please check my comment under your answer, thanks.

Comment: @mzoz I am not suggesting you should accept my answer.  Merely that you should not render existing answers incomplete by changing the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

System and/or library calls don't automatically print a message when there's an error.  That's up to you to do.  What these functions will do is return a particular value to indicate an error and also to set `errno` to indicate the specific error.  Then you can use `perror` to print the error string corresponding to the current value of `errno`.

In the case of `fopen`, it returns `NULL` if the call failed.  So you need check if it does so, and if so use `perror` to print the message.

```
FILE *fd = fopen("nothing", "r");
if (fd == NULL) {
    perror("fopen failed");
}
```

Doing things this way gives you more control over your program.  For example, there may be cases where you expect a file *not* to exist, so failing to open the file is not an error so in that case you don't want to print an error.

Comment: Thanks mate could you collaborate a bit more of my added questions?

Comment: @mzoz C has no exception handling, so there's nothing automatic.

Comment: so is `perror()` the only way to trigger `stderr` writing?

Comment: @mzoz That or using `fprintf(stderr, ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Failure to open a file that *does not exist* is not a "system error", - succeeding to open a file that does not exist would be an error!

Using `fopen()` to test for the existence of a file might be intentional behaviour - you would really not want to to report to `stderr` in that case.

The standard library will not report to `stderr`, all such output must be explicitly coded.  Your OS may report to `stderr` in the event of some fatal error such as a seg-fault, but that is a true *system error*, not simply normal and required behaviour.

Comment: Good point. A program may actually check whether a file exists and whether I can open it (or whether it does *not* exist or I cannot open it!) without relying on specific implementations by, well, trying to open it...

Comment: at least in man page it's defined as error `Upon successful completion fopen(), fdopen() and freopen() return a FILE pointer.  Otherwise, NULL is returned and errno is set to indicate the error.`, as long as it returns `NULL` it's considered an error

Comment: @mzoz If it returns NULL, it was _unsucessful_.  No one us saying otherwise.  That is not a _system error_. We are arguing semantics here, the point is it would be an error to report the condition by any means other than setting errno as documented.